# log4net is not rolling on Size

Tags: log4net

When I launch my app (MVVM Light WPF in c#) it generates 2 files `config_log.txt` and `config_log.txt.1`. As the app progresses `config_log.txt` grows in size but fails to roll over when in reaches 10KB. (`config_log.txt.1` remains empty).

When I close and restart my app, `config_log.txt` becomes `config_log.txt.2` and I now have 4 files in total (`config_log.txt` , `config_log.txt.1` , `config_log.txt.2` , `config_log.txt.3`)

I was expecting it to create a new backup only when the current backup file reached 10KB or the app was relaunched. (is this what aught to happen?) It seems to be creating extra files and grows in size above the 10KB limit.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

This is my log.config...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="log4net"
       type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler, log4net" />
  </configSections>
  <log4net>
    <root>

      <!--
      **
      ** Comment/Uncomment one of the following levels to enable/disable logging
      **
      -->
      <!--<level value="DEBUG" />-->
      <!--<level value="INFO" />-->
      <!--<level value="WARN" />-->
      <!--<level value="ERROR" />-->
      <!--<level value="FATAL" />-->
      <!--<level value="OFF" />-->
      <level value="DEBUG" />

      <appender-ref ref="HourlyAppender" />
      <!--<appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />-->
      <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender" />
    </root>

    <appender name="HourlyAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString" value="${ALLUSERSPROFILE}/Optex/RedwallServer/Log/config_log.txt" />
      <staticLogFileName value="false" />
      <appendToFile value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10K"/>
      <MaxSizeRollBackups value="4"/>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="" />
        <param name="Footer" value="" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
      <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR" />
        <foreColor value="White" />
        <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="INFO" />
        <foreColor value="Green" />
      </mapping>
      <mapping>
        <level value="WARN" />
        <foreColor value="Yellow" />
      </mapping>
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <!--<param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />-->
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%-5p %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="Header" value="[Header]\r\n" />
        <param name="Footer" value="[Footer]\r\n" />
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c %m%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
  </log4net>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I'm very new at this, but have you tried specifying the `maximumFileSize` as `10KB` instead of `10K`?

Comment: Also, it's possible you're mixing the pattern layouts. `PatternLayout` doesn't have `header` or `footer` params, but `DynamicPatternLayout` does. It's actually best to cut down your configuration to the bare minimum and make sure it works, then build optional/nice-to-have feature on top while still ensuring it works in every step.

Comment: @djikay, Thanks for spotting the '10KB' error, it now rolls when it reaches 10KB in size. I will look at your other suggestion tomorrow.

Comment: I had a closer look at the documentation and the header/footer should be ok actually. It must have been just the `B` that you were missing. However, it's worth removing from your configuration anything you don't need, in order to avoid any potential issues and to make any issues you may have easier to diagnose. In any case, I formatted my comments in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation for `maximumFileSize`](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.MaximumFileSize.html):

> This property allows you to specify the maximum size with the suffixes "KB", "MB" or "GB" so that the size is interpreted being expressed respectively in kilobytes, megabytes or gigabytes.
>   For example, the value "10KB" will be interpreted as 10240 bytes.

So you need a `B` with your size specification. If you replace this:

```
<maximumFileSize value="10K"/>
```

with this:

```
<maximumFileSize value="10KB"/>
```

it should work as you expect.